# Using multiple awk statements in a linux command

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, awk

I am executing a bash script in php file.

1. I have a text file.
2. I have to extract last 100 lines of the file.
3. In these 100 lines I have to extract lines with character "A" in third column.
4. Among these shortlisted lines I have to get the line number of the line whose second column has number "2".

This is my code, which is not providing any output.

```
<?php

$eff="195";
$chain="B";
$struct_pos="2";

$pre_line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk '$3==$chain'| awk -F' ' -v var=$struct_pos '{if ($2==var) print FNR}'");

?>
```

However, following codes works properly, in which I have removed one of the awk statements.

```
$pre_line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk -F' ' -v var=$struct_pos '{if ($2==var) print FNR}'");

$pre_line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk '$3==$chain'");
```

What is the solution to this problem ?

Comment: `awk '$3==$chain'` is wrong. You have to give the var `$chain` to `awk` with `-v`, as you do in the next pipe.

Comment: Thanks. But it works fine, if I dont use the subsequent awk statement ? This statement works fine: $pre_line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk '$3==$chain'");

Comment: Ah, makes sense because `php` may do the variable replacement first. Maybe you can join the two conditions into something like: `awk '$3==$chain && $2==$struct_pos {print NR}'`.

Comment: Thanks. thats work on command line, but i don't know why its not working in php. I re-wrote the command as follows: $pre_line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk '$3==$chain && $2==$struct_pos {print FNR}'");

Comment: Normally it is `tail -n 100 file` not `tail file -n 100`...

Comment: Not sure why one of your `awk`s has `-F` and the other does not when they are preumably still parsing the same file?

Comment: Your script will run into problems if there is more than one line of output - is that a problem? Maybe you need a `head -n 1` or a `tail -n 1` at the end?

Comment: It seems to me your file does not contain any records matching your two conditions in the last N lines.

Answer (score 0):

try this..,

```
$pre_line=exec("tail $i.dssp -n $eff | awk '$3==\"'$chain'\"'| awk -F' ' '{if ($2=='$struct_pos') print FNR}'");
```